# Dynamic resizing of page

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would like to try and accomplish this without resorting to jQuery.

I am trying to load a page where the content is dynamically re-sized based on the height and width of the browser. I presently have two iterations of the code, one with an image in the content div and another, much simpler, without.

Firstly, addressing the one without the image. Calling `winSize`from an `onload` event in the body tag or inside the script tag at the bottom of the HTML seems to be able to determine the scrollHeight/Width prior to setting the style, but fills the entire window with the black of the content div rather than setting its width to 704px  as the script has determined it should be. Using the `document.body.onload` in the script header to call `winSize` resulted in a null scrollWidth/Height and only displays the grey background.

The code for that is as as follows:

```
<style>
    body {
       padding:0px;
       background-color: #808080;
    }
    div { 
       position:absolute;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    bArat=3/2;
    bH1=0;
    bW1=0;
    bX1=0;
    bY1=0;
            
    function winSize(){
       winW=document.body.scrollWidth;
       winH=document.body.scrollHeight;
       _style();
    }
    
    function _style(){
       bH1=winH;
       bW1=bH1/bArat;
       bX1=(winW/2)-(bW1/2);
       document.getElementById("gutters").style.left=bX1;
       document.getElementById("gutters").style.top=bY1;
       document.getElementById("gutters").style.height=bH1;
       document.getElementById("gutters").style.width=bW1;
       document.getElementById("gutters").style.backgroundColor="black";
       document.body.style.backgroundColor="black";
    }
    
    //document.body.onload=winSize();
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="gutters">
    </div>
    <script>
    //winSize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Secondly, in the more complicated version of this script that includes a div within "gutters" that houses an `img` (soon to be multiple, as soon as this problem is solved), almost everything works fine except for when it loads, it does not load the styles (in Chrome). It does, however, load the styles on a refresh or if I set a 50ms delay on the `onload` trigger. I presume this is because Chrome (and Safari?) triggers the `onload` event after the html has loaded but before the image itself has been rendered, therefore the function cannot determine the height and width of the body that has not truly finished loading.

In this second script the function above:

```
function winSize(){
   winW=document.body.scrollWidth;
   winH=document.body.scrollHeight;
   _style();
}
```

does not work at all. `winH` or `winW` are not defined.

The function is snagged from http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm

```
function winSize(){
    if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
        winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
        winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
    document.documentElement &&
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
        winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
        winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
        winW = window.innerWidth;
        winH = window.innerHeight;
    }
}
```

works as described above: "...when it loads it does not load the styles (in Chrome). It does, however, load the styles on a refresh." If I run this second `winSize` function in the first script it returns the error "Cannot read property 'style' of null".

I prefer the first function for its brevity and (according to W3schools.com) better cross browser compatibility with `object.scrollWidth` over `window.innerWidth`, but clearly, one or both are broken in some context.

My questions are, in order of importance:

1. In the second script, how can I get the `winSize` function to run after the images have fully loaded? (if that is the issue)
2. Why are the two scripts having such drastically different reactions to the two functions when implemented in the same way.
3. What would fix the first script that I presented -- where the first content div, "gutters", is filling the entire screen rather than making a rectangle.
4. Why putting an `onload` event in the body tag works, but putting `document.body.onload` in the script of the head doesn't.

Sorry for such a long question--and so many questions in one, but I couldn't figure a way to untangle them. I would appreciate any help and forever praise those who can help me wrap my head around this.

Comment: 1) add `+"px"` to your sizes as in `..style.left=bX1+"px"`  2) where do you call the winsize now? I would expect a `window.onload=function() { winSize() }`

Comment: 3) was a stupid mistake on my part. I just found the line `  document.body.style.backgroundColor="black"; ` . Don't know how, or why it was there--but it's not any more.

Comment: Thanks mplungjan!
Adding `...+px` and using `window.onload` helped. I had tried calling it with `document.onload` . It does not appear to be necessary to call the within an anonymous function, may I ask why you suggested it? The only issue that arroze is that it appears to be retrieving the scrollheight/width as 246 x 341, when in this case it should be 1078 x 950. I solved the issue using `window.onresize=winSize`

Comment: There is no document.onload. If you use jQuery is is $(document).ready() and the onload in the body tag matches the window.onload

Comment: Ahh, I see. I used it based on this snippet "onload is Supported by the Following JavaScript Objects: Document, Window, XMLDocument, XMLHttpRequest" from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp , which evidently is incorrect.

Comment: Please read http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

why not just specify dimensions in % and let the browser do it.
May be you have some very specific requirement?
Please write the scenario, (in short)

Comment: I am setting up a page that is 8 panes, 4h x 2w, and animating it so that when one pane is clicked on the entire page zooms in. The user then has the pability to hover over the peripheral panes to make them central. <br/>
The reason why I cannot define the height and width in percentages is because I have no frame of referance for what the aspect ratio of the users screen will be. If I want my container div to be 0.75 as wide as it is high, I don't know how to define that